# xmpp framework ios BOSH support yet?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

great framework but wondering if there is any support for BOSH?

We've got limited access to ports in our company, and to make our messaging app useful we need it to run over HTTPS, which is going to require BOSH support.

In the latest master from github I don't see any reference to BOSH support, but want to double check here.  Any alternatives out there that do have BOSH support?

Thanks!